# GServer Thread Problems In Ruby

Tags: ruby

Looking around I found http://www.devco.net/archives/2008/06/26/adventures_with_ruby.php where the blogger moan about GServer's bug to destory threads and reaching its maximum connections. Is this problem real / still true?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problems when using GServer as simple TCP server, however I didn't dig into the issue too deeply since I had originally planned to use [EventMachine](http://rubyeventmachine.com/).

In the end I just ported my code to use that library and been happy.

Sorry, I don't know the real answer, but I do know that I had problems with GServer and have been really happy with EM since I switched -- so you might want to look into that.   Replacing libraries was not too difficult once I understood how EM worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had also faced two problems with GServer in Ruby 1.9.1.

1. It suddenly stops
2. It does memory leaks

http://tora-japan.com/wiki/GServer_in_Ruby_1.9.1_has_two_problems

Then, I wrote a Pre-Threaded TCP Server for Ruby 1.9.1 by myself,
linked from the wiki page above.

Answer (score 0):

Eventmachine is awesome:

class Server

```
module Thread_server

  def receive_data data

    data.chomp
    {.......................}

  end
end
```

def self.perform

```
  EventMachine::run {

  EventMachine::start_server "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", pxoxrxt, Thread_server

  }
```

end

end

Comment: EventMachine is indeed awesome, but can you better explain how this answers the OP's question? Are you suggesting that they use EventMachine instead of GServer?